# Change QR code color in Real Time

Tags: android, qr-code, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality, augmented-assignment

I want to change QR code's color to yellow color from its original black color in Real time. As per my understanding it will be the topic of Augmented Reality which is new for me. I already searched on Google but nothing relevant I found over there. Any suggestions or any help will be appreciated. As of now I have took one CameraView which is reading QR code. So, I want to change that QR code color to yellow color within CameraView as real time while user is scanning through his/her device.

[image: Example Real Time Change color of QR code while Reading]

Comment: @CommonsWare I already aware about to change color of image or bitmap which is already loaded in app or captured within app. My question is about to change QR code color in real time.

Comment: Since your code does not have a [mcve], it is reasonable to assume that the QR code is represented as a `Bitmap`. If you are using something else for your QR code, please provide a [mcve] showing how you are displaying the QR code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my question description.

Comment: @RonakJoshi can you share me on change color of qr code ?